# If statement turns page white

Tags: php

I am trying to get this if statement to work but the page turns white when i try to use it, anyone have any idea why ?

```
  if($shortUrlDomain['id'] != '1') && ($shortUrlDomain['remium_only'] != $Auth->id));
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
```

Comment: You're missing `(` before the condition.

Comment: Also, you have `;` after the condition, so the next block won't be conditionalized.